# Is it possible for Chrome's DevTools to display a website the real size it appears on a phone?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible for Chrome's DevTools to display a website the *real size* it appears on a phone?

Comment: Yes, you can toggle to device mode

Comment: It's not physically the same size of screen as my iPhone X

Comment: Maybe 'edit...' and add your own device???

Comment: I've also heard DevTools doesn't perfectly emulate what it'll look like on a phone which is...frustrating...Is it still worth testing on?

Comment: judging by the downvotes I'm guessing this wouldn't be a helpful feature. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just click on the icon "Toggle device toolbar" on the top left or press Ctrl + Shift + M while focus on DevTools Window.

Once you are on device mode, you can change the resolution at the top of the screen.